# How do I change LaTeX to MathML using MathJax in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, latex, mathjax, mathml

I'm trying to render math equations from user input server side using MathJax in Node.js. I'm using a separate library (mathjs) to turn the input into LaTeX, but after spending an hour looking at the MathJax docs I'm no closer to turning the LaTeX into MathML.

I'm assuming I'd be using the `mathjax` package on NPM, and then use the `MathJax.InputJax` and `MathJax.OutputJax` classes to do the processing, but I've got no idea how to put everything together.

(In case anyone is wondering, I'm using a CSS file to polyfill MathML, rather than load MathJax in the browser and cause a delay while the processing happens.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/) for this.  It is set up to run MathJax server-side.  There are a number of example command-line tools in the `bin` directory.  You could also hook up a web service to handle the conversion.  Tim Arnold made one available as [mathjax-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-server) on npmjs.com.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a deeper look at those two repos.

Comment: MathJax v3 now can run in node directly, so MathJax-node is no longer necessary.  See the [MathJax node demos](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-node) repository for examples.

Comment: Is there any way to convert LaTeX to MathML in React application (client-side)?

Comment: @BhuvanGandhi, if you are trying to obtain the MathML representation but not insert it into the document, you could simply load MathJax v3 and use its `MathJax.tex2mml()` function to get the MathML (serialize it using `MathJax.startup.toMML()`.  If you need to insert the MathML into the document, you would probably need to use one of the [MathJax react libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mathjax%20react) and modify it to use MathML output as in the [example](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/mathml.html#nativemml) in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, I have used `tex2mmlPromise()` function to convert LaTeX to MathML, thanks. You are doing a great job!